# RequireJS - skipDirOptimize: true setting does not optimize my main module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, uglifyjs

If I use RequireJS to optimize my whole project my main module will not get optimized/uglified if I use the setting skipDirOptimize: true. From my understanding everything should be optimized except the non-build layer JS files. Is this a bug or me not understanding the correct usage of this parameter?

Here is my requirejs config:

```
{
    appDir: '../project',
    mainConfigFile: '../project/assets/js/main.js',
    dir: '../httpdocs',
    optimize: "uglify",
    //Introduced in 2.1.2: If using "dir" for an output directory, normally the
    //optimize setting is used to optimize the build layers (the "modules"
    //section of the config) and any other JS file in the directory. However, if
    //the non-build layer JS files will not be loaded after a build, you can
    //skip the optimization of those files, to speed up builds. Set this value
    //to true if you want to skip optimizing those other non-build layer JS
    //files.
    skipDirOptimize: true,
    generateSourceMaps: false,
    normalizeDirDefines: "skip",
    uglify: {
        toplevel: true,
        ascii_only: true,
        beautify: false,
        max_line_length: 1000,
        defines: {
            DEBUG: ['name', 'false']
        },
        no_mangle: false
    },
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    removeCombined: true,
    modules: [
        {
            name: '../main'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the relative path in your module is probably causing r.js to not recognise it as a build bundle at the point where it decides whether or not to optimize it.

I had a similar problem (build bundles not being optimized), not with a relative module path but with a paths config to allow my modules to be named differently to my folder structure:

```
({
    ...
    skipDirOptimize: true,
    paths: {
        'MyLibrary': ''
    },
    modules: [
       { name: 'MyLibrary/Main' }
    ],
    ...
})
```

This causes the module name in r.js (2.1.8) to become `/Main`, so when it builds its `_buildPathToModuleIndex` mapping, the key will be incorrect due to having two slashes (e.g. `C:\dev\project\output\\Main`).

The way that the optimization loop decides if a module is a build bundle (and hence needs optimization even when `skipDirOptimize: true`) is by looking it up in the `_buildPathToModuleIndex` mapping using its filename (e.g. `C:\dev\project\output\Main`). Due to it being in the map with two slashes, it won't find it. Therefore it won't be considered to be a build bundle and won't be optimized.

Try putting some `console.log`s in r.js where it builds and accesses `_buildPathToModuleIndex` to see what it's putting in and what it uses to look it up.

For my problem, the solution was to add a paths entry for `'MyLibrary/Main': 'Main'` (repetition unfortunately). I'm not sure what your project structure is, but how about if you set `baseUrl: '../` and then simply call your module `main` ?